# How to construct a cube

Tags: geometry, education

My friend has asked me this question. I have no idea how to answer, but I think the question is  interesting enough to be noted here:

Consider 3 pieces of wire (not necessary of equal length). Is it possible to construct a cube from them by only bending or pasting them ?? (no cutting is allowed)

Comment: I take the question to be equivalent to a variant of a "Can you draw this figure without lifting your pen?"-type challenge. In this case, the figure is the (combinatorial) cube graph, and you're allowed to lift your pen *twice*. As @Angela's answer suggests, there's a simple test to determine when you *can't* draw a figure with $n$ pen-lifts. Which raises another question: Is there a test for when you *can*? (When $n = 0$, this is the [Euler-Hierholzer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path): a no-pen-lift path exists if and only if all vertices of the figure have even degree.)

Answer (score 8):

No. The cube has eight vertices of odd degree. If the wire is not doubled up anywhere then each vertex must be an endpoint of one of the pieces of wire, since otherwise the wire would go out for each time it goes in nd the degree would be even. Three pieces of wire have only six endpoints.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if we relaxed the rules by allowing a single wire to visit the same vertex twice (but not visit an edge more than once)? This would allow for the possibility of a vertex of odd degree that is not an endpoint of any wire.

Comment: @Adriano: Interesting !

Comment: @Adriano: Why would that change anything? Angela's (+1) answer did not use a rule that says a wire can visit a vertex only once!!

Comment: @Angela: what happens if we bend a wire at point $A$ and then paste an end point of another wire to $A$ ?? This gives us  verteces of degree 3

Comment: @AA: You're right that you can handle a vertex of degree 3 with a bend and an end. The key observation is that you don't have enough ends to handle *all eight* degree-3 vertices of the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> count the number of edges concurrent on each vertex